# Pretty_breaks not providing specified number of ticks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With my example data below, I'm trying to get the y axis ticks to look relatively stable across panels.

The issue is that with J6 and J7, which have much wider ranges, they're ending up with 4 ticks instead of the specified 3.

Are there any other ways to specify the number of axis ticks? Or does anyone else have a way to visualize this without the J6 and J7 totally squashing the Y axis for all the other panels?

Code

```
d2$decade <- factor(d2$decade, levels = c("1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", "2020s"))
d2$journal <- factor(d2$journal, levels = c("J1", "J2", "J3", "J4", "J5", "J6", "J7"))



calculate_breaks <- function(x) {
  # Define custom breaks based on the range of data in each facet panel
  breaks <- pretty(x, n = 3)
  return(breaks)
}

ggplot(d2, aes(x = decade, y = num)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = construct, group = construct),
             size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(color = construct, group = construct),
            linewidth = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~journal, nrow = 2,
             scales = "free_y",
             labeller = labeller(journal = c("J1" = "Journal Name 1",
                                             "J2" = "Journal Name 2",
                                             "J3" = "Journal Name 3",
                                             "J4" = "Journal Name 4",
                                             "J5" = "Journal Name 5",
                                             "J6" = "Journal Name 6",
                                             "J7" = "Journal Name 7"))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Passive" = "red",
                                "Active" = "green",
                                "Mistake" = "gray")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = calculate_breaks) +
  labs(x = "Decade",
       y = "Num") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 13) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Data

```
d2 <- structure(list(journal = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), levels = c("J1", "J2", "J3", "J4", "J5", "J6", "J7"
), class = "factor"), decade = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("1980s", "1990s", "2000s", "2010s", 
"2020s"), class = "factor"), construct = c("Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
"Active", "Active", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
"Active", "Active", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
"Active", "Active", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Active", "Passive", 
"Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Mistake", "Mistake", 
"Mistake", "Mistake", "Mistake", "Active", "Active", "Active", 
"Active", "Active", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", "Passive", 
"Passive"), num = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 16, 25, 26, 13, 3, 11, 
17, 19, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 10, 7, 3, 7, 7, 21, 8, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 11, 24, 28, 19, 0, 6, 15, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 
15, 12, 43, 36, 9, 18, 6, 33, 11, 7, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 18, 12, 21, 
18, 9, 19, 26, 14, 20, 12, 2, 3, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 20, 26, 12, 21, 
45, 58, 62, 33, 5, 6, 12, 40, 23, 0, 1, 6, 17, 6, 33, 51, 58, 
160, 81)), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: One semi-manual solution would be to use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales()` to specify your breaks for each facet:  https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#lists-of-scales

Comment: `pretty_breaks` uses `pretty` from base R, which does not promise to pick exactly as many breaks as requested, but a number "around" that, using 1/2/5 times a power of ten. See `?pretty` for details.

Comment: @JonSpring, is there an alternative that will actually pick exactly as many breaks as requested? I guess that's really the core of my question.

Comment: There are probably custom ways to accomplish that, but it will depend on what you want the breaks to be. (ie there are many potential approaches for picking breaks and limits for each facet. you haven't specified what the "right" one means for you.) Nothing would prevent you from using `facetted_pos_scales` and defining the exact breaks you want for each facet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a linear scale, with adequate space for the data in each facet, you might consider a layout with varying facet sizes. Then, with a little tweaking, you can get consistent scaling & ticks that still gives all the data the space it requires.

[image]

```
  ...
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars(journal),  scales = "free_y",
                      design = "
                      ABCG
                      DEFG") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(y = c(
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70)),
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,165), n.breaks = 10))) +
    ...
```

Comment: Oh this is a nice and elegant solution, thanks. I'm likely going to have to leave it in its original 4-3 layout but this might be good enough to be convincing otherwise!